# ng-filter with ng-repeat for objects (k, v)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using inbuilt Angular 1 filters and trying to filter out a property of an object. I am aware that Angular Filters do not accept an Object rather an Array, however, the way the webapp is designed I cannot refactor so I can pass an array instead of an object. The reason has to do with tracking each object by its value which is quite efficient. The caveat though with the data set is that it is huge. One table can contain up to 1000 rows. To give you a better understanding, my object looks like this:

```
{"UNIQUE-KEY-XYZ-123" : {"name" : "XYZ", "type" : "investment", "book", "ABC"}, "UNIQUE-KEY-LMN-321" : {"name" : "LMN", "type" : "investment", "book", "STU"}, ...}
```

```
<tr><td><input ng-model="foo.book"></td></tr>     
<tr ng-repeat="(key, row) in blotter.rows track by key | filter:foo" ng-class="{flash: blotter.flashList[key]['all']}">
```

Filtering works fine if I pass an array rather than the object but help me figure out a way so it works with object too. Some people suggested using [this external module](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter) but I believe the way it is implemented is very inefficient.

Comment: Can you add a jsFiddle for your problem?

Comment: default filters will not work for objects. either you can write your own filter or use any external libraries if available.

Comment: See [AngularJS Developer Guide - Creating Custom Filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter#creating-custom-filters).

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [ng-change directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) to create the filtered object:

```
<tr>
  <td><input ng-model="foo.book"
             ng-change="filteredRows=myFilter(blotter.rows, foo.book) />
  </td>
</tr>     
<tr ng-repeat="(key, row) in filteredRows track by key" 
    ng-class="{flash: blotter.flashList[key]['all']}">
</tr>
```

JS

```
$scope.myFilter = function(data, selector) {
    var filteredRows = {};
    //Code here
    return filteredRows;
};
```

Using the `ng-change` directive is more efficient than using the watcher in the `ng-repeat` and the dirty checking mechanism of the digest cycle.